# Android AltBeacon Library: Doesn't find beacons until restart phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I try to find surrounding beacons with the ParserLayout: "m:2-3=beac,i:4-5,i:6-23,p:24-24,d:25-25" to send 18 Bytes of custom payload.
I try to monitor them with this region: Region("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2", 10000, null, null)

My beacon does look like that:

```
val payload = ByteArray(18)
val beacon: Beacon = Beacon.Builder()
            .setIdentifiers(mutableListOf(10000, payload.toIdentifier()))
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .setDataFields(mutableListOf<Long>(1, 2, 3)) // only to set != null
            .build()
```

It works properly, but if I'm developing "longer" it seems that I can't find the beacons any more.

After restarting my phone, it detects beacons correctly..

somebody any idea how to prevent this behaviour?

Following the log:

```
I/BeaconManager: Starting foreground beacon scanning service.
I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner
I/BeaconService: beaconService version 2.16.4 is starting up on the main process
I/BeaconService: longScanForcingEnabled to keep scans going on Android N for > 30 minutes
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
D/Notification: allPendingIntents
I/BeaconService: starting with intent Intent { cmp=de.conlance.digital_meets_android.demo/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService }
I/BeaconService: starting with intent Intent { cmp=de.conlance.digital_meets_android.demo/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService }
    binding
I/BeaconTransmitter: Advertisement start succeeded.
I/BeaconService: start monitoring received
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
I/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Successfully saved new distance model file
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
I/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Successfully updated distance model with latest from online database
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
I/chatty: uid=10497(u0_a497) CycledLeScanner identical 2 lines
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
I/chatty: uid=10497(u0_a497) CycledLeScanner identical 1 line
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=251KB, data=182KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=223KB, data=124KB
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan with callback
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
```

Comment: How are you detecting these beacons?   Are you starting ranging?  Are you starting monitoring?  You say the problem is in detecting, so you really need to show the code you use to detect.  It would also be helpful to be more specific about the conditions under which you get detections and when they stop.  (Saying “developing ‘longer’” is not very specific.)

Comment: I start monitoring on the above described region. Then I should come into the callback "didEnterRegion(r: Region)" where I start ranging on "Region(r.uniqueId, null, null, null)" and there I handle my logic to match the right case.
I can't descibe it, but I ran several times in this issue and thought somebody else has the same issue. After restarting the phone all is fine.
I'm afraid, that this behaviour is same in productive on the phone...

Comment: Now I get: Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
This only gets called, if there are no beacons right?
But my 2nd phone is advertising right now...

Comment: No, the “non-distinct” log line shows up only if a beacon *IS* detected.

Comment: Ok,
How can I debug the behaviour, that I sometimes can not detect beacons and sometimes I can with the same phones and same beacons I start.

I know it's very difficult to help, but maybe you have an idea how to get the solution...